# Break out of for each loop JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am writing JQuery script to determine when an element of fixed height is filled by content equalling greater height, at which point I want it to create a new identical element for all of the overflowing content to flow into. I want it to do this automatically on repeat.

I have this down for the most part, but am experiencing a problem because of the "for each" loop I'm running on the child elements.

While the script effectively creates a new page once the first page has overflowed, and it successfully moves the overflowing content into the new page, it does this for each new child thereafter irregardless of the fact that the content height should be reset. The way I see it, I need to prompt the creation of the new page in the loop to transfer the current child element over into it. I tried escaping the loop with a "return false;" which breaks the entire script.

HTML:

```
<div id="page-container">
  <div class="page">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas fringilla ipsum vitae neque fermentum, a sagittis magna lacinia. Nullam eget nibh nulla. Vivamus tellus lectus, ullamcorper sit amet diam eget, placerat gravida enim. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce condimentum risus sed nunc feugiat maximus. Sed tincidunt nisi velit, et hendrerit dolor suscipit eu. Aenean dui nulla, tempus eu posuere congue, iaculis eu sapien. Phasellus volutpat nisi dui, a malesuada justo posuere vitae. Sed dolor turpis, porta a libero sed, rutrum elementum augue. Proin diam nibh, gravida eget velit nec, tempor consectetur felis.</p>
  <p>Aliquam interdum accumsan nisl eget ullamcorper. Morbi id ornare dui. Aliquam euismod efficitur magna ut vestibulum. Sed pellentesque metus vitae quam feugiat, eu ultricies ipsum tristique. Ut in diam quis nulla aliquam dictum. Aenean sapien leo, rutrum quis posuere quis, convallis sit amet nisi. Aenean ac pellentesque metus. Phasellus luctus sapien at massa interdum lacinia. Suspendisse lacus eros, luctus pellentesque diam a, tempor semper nunc. Vestibulum accumsan nec felis vitae finibus. In viverra aliquet est, eu semper tellus. Etiam interdum dignissim euismod. Curabitur iaculis tellus at semper suscipit. Quisque sed risus neque.</p>
  <p>Phasellus tincidunt diam id finibus tempor. Pellentesque vel ultrices neque. Suspendisse potenti. Pellentesque eget gravida sapien. Pellentesque malesuada bibendum viverra. Phasellus at ante nec turpis placerat placerat. Pellentesque sed nisl ut eros finibus faucibus. Duis dignissim ut sapien eget faucibus. Mauris sem risus, consequat scelerisque dui quis, consectetur vestibulum nisi. Morbi nisl nisl, lobortis vel risus rhoncus, accumsan scelerisque nisi.</p>
  <p>Maecenas odio arcu, aliquet in accumsan id, blandit vitae tortor. Nunc nec aliquet nisl. Nullam tempus turpis dolor, quis vestibulum tortor mollis vel. Sed sed ultrices ex. Curabitur accumsan arcu nec elit molestie tristique in quis lectus. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam varius sapien gravida finibus euismod. Mauris semper consectetur massa, ut sagittis arcu. Mauris suscipit lectus id dolor semper lacinia.</p>
  <p>Nunc a arcu diam. Fusce at mauris molestie, tempor nulla sed, mollis odio. Cras commodo nibh a felis aliquet tempor. Donec vitae nisi ut leo tincidunt auctor. Nam eleifend non odio quis rutrum. Curabitur scelerisque orci vel felis accumsan finibus. Vivamus ut hendrerit diam, in blandit metus. Vestibulum mollis odio arcu, ac elementum leo iaculis sit amet. Vestibulum mollis mattis nunc molestie pulvinar. Etiam ante nibh, ullamcorper nec turpis id, pretium euismod nisi. Aliquam scelerisque, metus ac laoreet iaculis, nulla mauris tristique ligula, sed sagittis risus massa quis lectus. Maecenas nec nisl ullamcorper, vehicula dui et, hendrerit risus. Quisque volutpat urna imperdiet lobortis molestie. Quisque at dapibus quam. Etiam neque mi, bibendum sit amet facilisis a, ullamcorper a enim.</p>
  <p>Cras quam massa, facilisis ut elementum vel, maximus ut augue. In sem odio, blandit eu urna eget, sollicitudin convallis eros. Praesent eget lorem nec lorem faucibus euismod. Phasellus ullamcorper tristique velit sed facilisis. Etiam et lectus fringilla, tristique urna sit amet, sagittis lacus. Phasellus at erat malesuada, imperdiet nunc vel, tempor mi. Vestibulum vulputate felis sed lectus fermentum dignissim. Quisque dictum posuere tincidunt. In sit amet ante sodales, iaculis ipsum sit amet, dignissim ex. In nec turpis leo. Donec iaculis pulvinar neque nec maximus.</p>
  <p>Cras auctor posuere dolor. Quisque venenatis risus sit amet lacus viverra, vitae placerat sem scelerisque. Curabitur id pellentesque lacus. In mi eros, tincidunt nec est id, auctor elementum felis. Aenean varius elementum aliquam. Fusce vehicula ipsum eget enim tincidunt, id maximus felis condimentum. Suspendisse at dignissim enim, vitae viverra sem.</p>
  <p>Vivamus vitae mi id mauris varius pretium. Mauris eu nibh nec eros varius placerat. Mauris ut nulla consectetur, egestas ante id, congue leo. Vestibulum sit amet ipsum ligula. Suspendisse sed dui sed ante tempor volutpat. Duis placerat, augue non sagittis ultrices, nibh arcu fringilla dolor, eu vestibulum mi lectus et quam. Sed euismod eget neque ut venenatis. Cras metus sem, malesuada id tristique vitae, aliquet et felis. Vivamus sed elementum tortor, eget cursus mi. Suspendisse dui est, feugiat vulputate velit ac, consectetur viverra mi. Aenean porttitor turpis leo, a convallis lacus tincidunt at. Pellentesque quam nulla, dictum id sem maximus, aliquet maximus lorem.</p>
  <p>Mauris ut porttitor purus, a sagittis purus. Cras at mauris nec est aliquam malesuada ut at diam. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nam sodales vestibulum dui vitae eleifend. Proin a lacus id lacus pulvinar aliquet. Donec vel eros sem. Fusce pharetra tincidunt odio ac malesuada. Aliquam pellentesque purus non rhoncus fermentum. Integer ultrices id neque id congue. Quisque mollis non velit quis tincidunt. Pellentesque semper commodo massa, vitae dapibus leo feugiat vel. Duis sit amet dignissim nibh.</p>
  <p>Curabitur vitae pharetra mi. Nullam id ligula sed orci cursus suscipit a ut erat. In non fermentum neque. Aenean quis luctus tellus, sit amet accumsan leo. Aenean vel libero rhoncus, cursus nisl non, maximus lorem. Aliquam facilisis leo leo. Maecenas semper nunc arcu, eu blandit ante posuere sed. Phasellus dapibus purus lacus, interdum dapibus est tristique vel. Mauris luctus est a orci ultricies, vel gravida diam porta. Donec fermentum vestibulum bibendum. Quisque pretium maximus sollicitudin. Praesent mollis neque nisl. Praesent dignissim porttitor commodo. Donec non sapien fringilla, iaculis ante sed, consectetur quam. Maecenas condimentum lorem leo, at varius nisi malesuada sit amet. Sed vehicula magna leo, id accumsan ex ultricies eget.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Fonts */
/** Garamond Cormorant (regular, italic, bold and bold italic) **/
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cormorant+Garamond:400,400i,700,700i');

/* General / boilerplate styles */
/** Page **/
* { -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }
html, body { height: 100%; }
html { font-size: 6.25%; }
body { margin: 0; }
/** Typography **/
body { font-family: 'Cormorant Garamond', serif; font-size: 16em /* 16px */; }
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p { margin: 0 0 0.5rem 0; }
h1 { font-size: 4em; } h2 { font-size: 3.5em; } h3 { font-size: 3em; }
h4 { font-size: 2.5em; } h5 { font-size: 2em; } h6 { font-size: 1.5em; }
p { font-size: 1em; line-height: 1.5; }
.paragraph { text-indent: 2em; }
.center { text-align: center; }
.justify { text-align: justify; }
blockquote { margin: 1rem 4em 1rem 4em; }
q { quotes: "\201C" "\201D" "\2018" "\2019"; }
html[lang="fr"] q { quotes: "\00ab" "\00bb"; }
cite { font-style: normal; }
cite:before { content: "\0020\2014\0020"; }
/** Media **/
figure { margin: 1em; text-align: center; }
@media (min-width: 750px) {
  .inline-left { float: left; margin: 1em 1em 1em 0; } 
  .inline-right { float: right; margin: 1em 0 1em 1em; }
}
figure img { display: inline; max-width: 100%; margin: 0.5em 0; }
.greyscale { -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); filter: grayscale(100%); }
.sepia { -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); filter: sepia(100%); }

/* Thematic styles */
body {
    padding: 1em;
    background: url(https://images.freecreatives.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Download-High-Quality-Wood-Background-Wallpaper-for-Your-Desktop.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
.page {
    width: 600px;
    height: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    padding: 2em;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    background: #F8ECC2;
    color: #0c0d0d;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
// On document load...
$(document).ready(function() {
  // For each page...
  $('.page').each(function () {
    // Get page height
    var pageHeight = $(this).height(); 
    // Initialize content height
    var contentHeight = 0;
    // For each element of the page...
    $(this).children().each(function () {
      // Add element height to overall content height
      contentHeight += $(this).outerHeight();
      // When the content height becomes greater than the page height...
      if (contentHeight > pageHeight) {
        // Append a new '.page' to the '#page-container'
        $(this).parent().after('<div class="page"></div>');
        // Append the current, overflowing element to the next page
        $(this).appendTo($(this).parent().next($('.page')));
      }
    });
  });
});
```

If any of this is unclear, the Codepen should clear it up nicely.

https://codepen.io/christophercostello/pen/yXPBaN

Comment: Can you boil this down into a smaller, more **minimal** example? I have no idea why there's CSS in a JavaScript question.

Comment: You mention it "breaks the entire script" when you try to `return false`. That seems to be the correct way to break out. Your example doesn't show this return false you have tried -- mind including it and telling us the console error?

Comment: I don't know why you are getting downvotes. Your problem is clear, you have a good working example in codepen. The example is small enough, these guys just want quick rep I think.

Comment: @Chris You don't get rep by downvoting. In fact, downvoting an answer subtracts from your rep.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are in a loop, `return false` to exit it

Your code is correct, there is no code to execute when returning false, so nothing happens.

```
$.each(array, function(idx, value){
    if(condition){ 
        return true; // this will go to the next iteration
    }else {
        return false; // this will exit the loop
    }
});
```

If you are in a for loop, make the condition `false` or `break`.

```
for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(condition){ 
        break;
    }else {
         // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Why make an other check when you can simply use `break;`?

Comment: You are right, I was trying to demonstrate that it could be any condition to break the loop.